# Изменить данные из файла с сохранением в другой файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Есть вот такие строки:

```
2018-02-23,15
2018-02-24,32
2018-02-25,16
2018-02-26,70
2018-02-27,28
2018-02-28,14
2018-03-01,27
2018-03-02,29
2018-03-03,81
```

Пытаюсь перевести вот в такой вот вид:

```
60,0 01.08.2017
59,0 02.08.2017
60,0 03.08.2017
60,0 04.08.2017
60,0 05.08.2017
```

Изменение строки невозможно, запись в другой список очевидна, но вот тут трудности: пытаюсь поменять через запись в файл, но не хватает знаний.

Переводит в список элементов, но ни реплейс, ни сплитануть не даёт сделать, и я понятия не имею как сделать.

```
import regex
file = open(r"C:\Users\Chechire Cat\Downloads\multiTimeline(1).csv", "r+")
file1 = open(r"C:\Users\Chechire Cat\PycharmProjects\mosia\primer1.csv", "w+")
content = file.read()
file.close()
print(content)
mylist = list()
d = (regex.findall("\d*\-\d*\-\d*\,\d*", content))
for i in range(len(d)):
for j in range(len(d[i])):
    if d[i][j] == "-":
        d[i][j].replace("-", ".")
    elif d[i][j] == ",":
        mylist.append(" ")
    else: mylist.append(d[i][j])
print(mylist)

for k in range(len(mylist)):
    file1.write(mylist[k-1])

file1.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как `2018-02-23,15` стал `60,0 01.08.2017`?

Comment: Прости, неправильно обьяснил. из такого вот вида перевести в такой.

Comment: Ну, я могу написать как из файла считать данные, обработать и в тот же файл записать, устроит?

Comment: если знаки поменяються на нужные, а также значение и дата поменяються местами, то это будет идеально

Comment: Пытался так вот поменять, но не получилось
import regex
file = open(r"C:\Users\Chechire Cat\Downloads\multiTimeline(1).csv", "r+")
file1 = open(r"C:\Users\Chechire Cat\PycharmProjects\mosia\primer1.csv", "w+")
content = file.read()
file.close()
print(content)
mylist = list()
for i in range(len(d)):
    for j in range(len(d[i])):
        if d[i][j] == "-":
            d[i][j].replace("-", ".")
        elif d[i][j] == ",":
            mylist.append(" ")
        else: mylist.append(d[i][j])
        if j == len(d[j]):
            print("\n")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) (предназначен для обработки табличных данных):

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\file.csv', header=None, names=['dt','val'], parse_dates=['dt'])
   [['val','dt']]
   .to_csv(r'd:\temp\result.csv', index=False, header=None, date_format='%d.%m.%Y'))
```

Результат:

```
15,23.02.2018
32,24.02.2018
16,25.02.2018
70,26.02.2018
28,27.02.2018
14,28.02.2018
27,01.03.2018
29,02.03.2018
81,03.03.2018
```

---

**UPDATE:** чтобы пропустить несколько начальных строк можно воспользоваться параметром `skiprows`:

```
(pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\file.csv', header=None, names=['dt','val'], parse_dates=['dt'], skiprows=3)
   [['val','dt']]
   .to_csv(r'd:\temp\result.csv', index=False, header=None, date_format='%d.%m.%Y'))
```

Comment: прошу прощения, но как убрать из файла также лишние строки?
Google умеет испортить праздник, и добавить в файл разной билиберды. как его можно почистить, кроме как по индексу срез взять

Comment: а как выглядят эти лишние строки? Они разбросаны по файлу случайным образом или только в начале или в конце?

Comment: я добавил в вопрос изображение

Comment: начинаю уже надоедать, можна ли вывести значение val в формате float&

Answer (score 1):

Работаем с файлами как есть:

**input.txt:**

```
2018-02-23,15
2018-02-24,32
2018-02-25,16
2018-02-26,70
2018-02-27,28
2018-02-28,14
2018-03-01,27
2018-03-02,29
2018-03-03,81
```

**Код:**

```
import datetime as DT


with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = []

    for line in f:
        # Тут происходит обработка строк
        line = line.rstrip()

        date, number = line.split(',')

        # Изменение формата даты: 2018-02-23 -> 23.02.2018
        date = DT.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

        # Сохранение каждой обработанной строки в список
        lines.append('{},{}\n'.format(number, date))

print(lines)  # ['15,23.02.2018\n', '32,24.02.2018\n', '16,25.02.2018\n', ...

# Запись всех строк в файл
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

**output.txt**

```
15,23.02.2018
32,24.02.2018
16,25.02.2018
70,26.02.2018
28,27.02.2018
14,28.02.2018
27,01.03.2018
29,02.03.2018
81,03.03.2018
```

---

**PS.** Если данных в файле не на гигабайты, то этот алгоритм, который собирает все данные в память и обрабатывает, пойдет.

Иначе лучше в сразу считывать, анализировать и записывать в отдельный файл. Т.е. открывается текущий файл в чтении, и открывается другой файл в запись, и при чтении по строке из файла_1 происходит обработка строки и сразу запись строчки в файл_2

Comment: При такой записи мы получаем масив str, но дальше я не могу понять. 
Прости что скидываю свой корявый, но твой я вообще не понимаю

Comment: В комментарии код невозможно увидеть, лучше в вопрос добавьте (кнопка `править`). А по поводу моего кода, сделайте свою обработку в цикле `for line in f:` и просто запишите результат. Обновил пример в ответе, стало понятнее? :)

Comment: Понятнее стало, спасибо, но как мне поменять значения и время местами?

Comment: сделать split и написать наоборот. Переписал код в ответе )

Comment: Огромное спасибо, выручили)